# $1\le p,q \le \infty$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ Let $K_p(A) =\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|_p$ then prove that $ K_p(A)=K_q(A^t)$

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-norms

> A be invertible matrix such that $1\le p,q \le \infty$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ Let $K_p(A) =\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|_p$ then prove that $ K_p(A)=K_q(A^t)$

---

One hint is given here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3349025/750552 .
$$\|A\|_p = \sup_{\|x\|_p = 1} \|A x\|_p = \sup_{\|x\|_p = 1} \sup_{\|y\|_q = 1} |y^T A x|$$
and $$\|A^t\|_q = \sup_{\|x\|_q = 1} \|A^t x\|_q = \sup_{\|x\|_q = 1} \sup_{\|y\|_p = 1} |y^T A^t x|$$

Then we have to prove that  $$\sup_{\|x\|_q = 1} \sup_{\|y\|_p = 1} |y^T A^t x| =\sup_{\|x\|_p = 1} \sup_{\|y\|_q = 1} |y^T A x| $$

I don't understand how prove it ??

Comment: What does the superscript in $A^t$ stand for?

Comment: Transpose of matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First transpose and then rename:$$\begin{align}\sup_{\|x\|_q = 1} \sup_{\|y\|_p = 1} |y^T A^t x|&=
\sup_{\|x\|_q = 1} \sup_{\|y\|_p = 1} |x^TAy|\\
&=\sup_{\|y\|_q = 1} \sup_{\|x\|_p = 1} |y^TAx|.
\end{align}$$